# Continuity between two metric-spaces

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

How to prove (without sequences) that $id: (\mathbb{R},|.|)\to (\mathbb{R},d)$ is continuous?

where $d(x,y)=|\exp(x)-\exp(y)|$

can we say: id  is continuous iff $$\forall x_0 \in \Bbb{R}, \forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta>0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}; |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |\exp(x)-\exp(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$ ? but how to obtain this?

Comment: It depends on how much you are allowed to assume, what your definition of $\exp$ is etc. Because saying $\text{id}$ is a continuous map between the two metric spaces is the same as $\exp: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function (in the usual sense with $|\cdot|$ as the metric on both domain and target) It is usually proven (or defined) in analysis courses that $\exp$ is an analytic function on $\Bbb{R}$ (has a convergent power series), hence continuity is trivial. (Also, I edited to add the condition "$\forall x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$", which you missed out)

Answer (score 0):

The condition in question is nothing but continuity of the exponential function (in the standard metric). So, try to re-create the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof and you are done.

Comment: how re-create  ? I don't understand???

Comment: Simply write down the standard proof of continuity of the exponential function

Comment: I don't know it , here i don't see how to get delta?

Comment: we don't have that $|\exp(x)-\exp(x_0)|\leq |x-x_0|$ so how to do ?

Comment: @PolineSandra $\exp(x)$ is differentiable so continuous. Use that to conclude $\delta$ exists. Done. Just use what you know from calculus.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically demonstrated that the identity is continuous iff $\exp(x)$ is continuous and I am pretty confident you're allowed to use this as a standard fact in topology (or metric space theory, real analysis, or whatever this course is) that $\exp(x)$ is a differentiable hence continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$. The problem staters also assume you know about $\exp(x)$ (and its basic properties).